# C# .Net Core 2 DI, how can I register an interface with a class that also take the same interface as constructor a parameter (Decorator)

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have a Repository that implement a IRepository interface. I have created a CachedRepository that also implement IRepository but it take a IRepository as constructor argument. Also, I know that I will eventually create an Oracle11Repository that inherit Repository to override some Repository method.

My objectif is to be able to swap these 3 Repositorys in the startup.cs without modifying the rest of the app.

How can I register the IRepository to use CachedRepository, specifying that the CachedRepository must use the Repository as is own IRepository?

Obviously, i got the error "A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'IRepository'"

Or maybe it's my approch that is not correct?

```
//Repository.cs
public class Repository : IRepository
{
        private readonly IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory;
        private readonly ILogger<Repository> logger;

        public AssessmentRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory, ILogger<Repository> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<PagedEnvelope<SearchResult>> Search(string term)
        {}
}
```

```
//CachedRepository.cs
public class Repository : IRepository
{
        private IRepository repos;
        private readonly ILogger<Repository> logger;
        private IMemoryCache cache;

        public CachedREpository(IRepository repos, ILogger<Repository> logger,  IMemoryCache cache, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.repos = repos;
            this.logger = logger;
            ConfigureCache(cache, configuration);
        }

        public async Task<PagedEnvelope<SearchResult>> Search(string term)
        {
            // If not in cache, call repos.Search(term) then cache and return 
        }
}
```

```
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddTransient<IRepository, CachedRepository>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to set up `Repository` as a base class for your functionality, and a base interface that will make bases consistent for future injection, so a rename and a new interface might be in order. So lets say your database is SQL, and your `Repository` class declaration would become

```cs
public class SqlRepository : IRepositoryBase
{
    // SQL Specific Search Method
}
```

and the base repository interface is now

```cs
public interface IRepositoryBase
{
    public Task<PagedEnvelope<SearchResult>> Search(string term);
}
```

You now have an implementation specific to your SQL access and an interface for injection, and then you inject it into your `CachedRepository` class like below.

```cs
public class CachedRepository : IRepository
{
    private IRepositoryBase _reposBase;
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public CachedREpository(IRepositoryBase reposBase,   
                        IMemoryCache cache, 
                        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this._reposBase = reposBase;
        this._cache = cache;
        // Note I took the logger out, you have it in the _reposBase object now. 
        ConfigureCache(cache, configuration);
    }

    public async Task<PagedEnvelope<SearchResult>> Search(string term)
        {
            // If not in cache, call _reposBase.Search(term) then cache and return 
        }

}
```

Now in your `Startup` class, you can use 2 injections to configure it how you want it:

```cs
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    // Set up injection for Base first
    services.AddTransient<IRepositoryBase, SqlRepository>();

    // Then set up injection for your Cached repo
    services.AddTransient<IRepository, CachedRepository>();
}
```

Now you have some flexibility built in, because to change to an Oracle DB, you just create the Oracle repository base:

```cs
public class OracleRepository : IRepositoryBase
{
    // Oracle Specific Search Method
}
```

and then in your DI container just change the line

```cs
services.AddTransient<IRepositoryBase, SqlRepository>();
```

to

```cs
 services.AddTransient<IRepositoryBase, OracleRepository>();
```

and you've switched database implementations by adding 1 new DB class, and then changing 1 line in startup, and this leaves your caching behavior alone.

Above discusses switching your base database, but you could of course change the level up as well, so `CachedRepository` can be switched out for anything that implements the `IRepository` interface, so you get the flexibility built into that layer as well.

From what I read of your question I think I understand and this appears to solve your problem. No more circular dependency.

Please comment if not, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for taking time to respond @nik-p. The problem with this approach, wich is to have two distinct interface for Repository and CachedRepository, is that if I dont wan't to use caching, I will have to change the signature of the controllers constructors from IRepository to IRepositoryBase.

Comment: You can also have the concrete RepositoryBase class implement ```IRepository```, and then you can inject the base as standalone if required, hence no caching. So your base SQL would look like ```public class SqlRepository: IRepositoryBase, IRepository```. Would that work? This way you could have them all conform to the same interface for injection, but use the ```CachingRepository``` to extend functionality of the bases. This would clean up the answer you posted a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly find a way to acheive that.

```
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //...
  // Register a concrete implementation so DI know how to construct it with dependency
  services.AddTransient<Oracle11Repository>();

  // Register a call back to tell specific IRepository to inject
  services.AddTransient<IRepository>(sp =>
                new CachedRepository(
                    sp.GetService<Oracle11Repository>(),
                    sp.GetService<ILogger<CachedRepository>>(),
                    sp.GetService<IMemoryCache>(),
                    sp.GetService<IConfiguration>())
  );
```

Now it would be nice to not have to specify all others constructors arguments since they are all registred.